# Spring @RequestMapping consumes charset?

Tags: spring, character-encoding, httprequest

I'm trying to use `@RequestMapping` with the `consumes`-element. Reading the [API-document](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) it works on the `Content-Type`-header of the request. However, using

```
@RequestMapping(consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", value = "/test")
public void test() {
  :
}
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1", value = "/test")
public void test() {
  :
}
```

doesn't make a difference. The header in the request can look like

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
```

or

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

`test()` will be called in all four possible constellations.

However, and this is proof to me that Spring sees and tries to use the `charset`-part, if I specify

```
@RequestMapping(consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-x8", value = "/test")
public void test() {
  :
}
```

I get an exception during startup (!) of the web-app:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed;
    nested exception is java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: UTF-x8
```

Note that the documentation on the `produces`-element also doesn't mention the use of `charset`, but according to Google some use it.

Any clues to what's happening here or what I'm doing wrong?

BTW, this is Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you have already answered your question, so this is more of a confirmation, from a code point of view, as to why the `charset` is not taken into account when resolving mappings.

When digging into Spring code, the culprit seems to be the [`MediaType#includes()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/3.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/http/MediaType.java?av=f#468). method

More digging reveals that a [`RequestMappingInfo`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/RequestMappingInfo.html) is created in association to the [`RequestMapping`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) annotation of the method. This `RequestMappingInfo` stores a series of `AbstractRequestCondition` objects, one of them being the [`ConsumesRequestCondition`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ConsumesRequestCondition.html) which holds the [`MediaType`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html) defined in the `consumes` part of the annotation (i.e. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8`).

Later when a request is made, this `ConsumesRequestCondition` has an [inner `ConsumeMediaTypeExpression` class with a `matchMediaType()` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/3.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ConsumesRequestCondition.java?av=f#213) that extracts the `MediaType` of the `HttpServletRequest` and checks it against it's own `MediaType` to see if it's included.

If you look at the `MediaType#includes()` implementation (Lines 426 to 428), it returns true when `type` (i.e. `application`) and `subtype` (i.e. `x-www-form-urlencoded`) are equal, completely disregarding the `parameters` Map which in this case 
holds the remnant `"charset","UTF-8"` combination.

Digging into the `produces` track seems to show similar results, but in this case it's the [`MediaType#isCompatibleWith()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/3.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/http/MediaType.java#502) method involved, and again, it reaches only to `type` and `subtype` if they are equal.

If you found evidence on Google of the `produces` working for charset request mapping, I would doubt it (unless they changed core Spring stuff)

As to why it was designed this way, well that's another question :)

Comment: Whow, thanks for that thorough investigation. As far as Google is concerned, well, I found code snippets. That means I'm not saying that I know that they are working, but why else would somebody put it into the code? (*This was a rhetorical question*)